# closures and memory leaks

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a page with a script that does only 2 things: change the color or a background and keep a time counter. There's a memory leak somewhere.

The JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5aREV/)

This is the script:

```
var TheDateToday = new Date();

var TheColorEffect = (function () {

   var TheColorArray = ['red', 'blue', 'purple'];

   return function () {

       var TheColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
       var TheOpacity = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 80) / 100;

       document.getElementById('TheText').style.color = TheColorArray[TheColor];
       document.getElementById('TheText').style.opacity = TheOpacity;

       document.getElementById('ThePanel').style.backgroundColor = TheColorArray[TheColor];
       document.getElementById('ThePanel').innerText = TheDateToday.toTimeString();
       };
   }());

var TheDateIncrement = (function () {

   return function () {
        TheDateToday.setSeconds(TheDateToday.getSeconds() + 10); };
}());

setInterval(TheDateIncrement, 10000);
setInterval(TheColorEffect, 2000);
```

and this is the css/html:

```
 #TheText{
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    margin:20px 20px;
    -webkit-transition:color 2s ease;
    -moz-transition:color 2s ease;
    -o-transition:color 2s ease;
    transition:color 2s ease;}

   #ThePanel{
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    clear:both;
    color:white;
    padding:20px 20px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transition:background 2s ease;
    -moz-transition:background 2s ease;
    -o-transition:background 2s ease;
    transition:background 2s ease;}​


<div id="TheText">This is a test text</div>
<div id="ThePanel"></div>​
```

When you go to Timeline in chrome and look at the memory usage, it just goes up. And if you open several of these pages in separate tabs, the CPU can get to 90% usage.

Where's the leak??
Thanks for your suggestions on fixing this.

Comment: I believe the issue might be each call returns a new function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code to this, found cpu and memory reduced. The function timing calls are reduced while testing the load.

```
var TheColorEffect = new function () {

    var TheDateToday = new Date();
    var TheColorArray = ['red', 'blue', 'purple'];
    var TheColor = 0;
    var TheOpacity = 0;

    this.change = function () {
        TheColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        TheOpacity = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 80) / 100;

        document.getElementById('TheText').style.color = TheColorArray[TheColor];
        document.getElementById('TheText').style.opacity = TheOpacity;
        document.getElementById('ThePanel').style.backgroundColor = TheColorArray[TheColor];
        document.getElementById('ThePanel').innerText = TheDateToday.toTimeString();

    }

    this.TheDateIncrement = function () {
        TheDateToday.setSeconds(TheDateToday.getSeconds() + 10);
    }

};


setInterval(TheColorEffect.TheDateIncrement, 200);
setInterval(TheColorEffect.change, 100);
```

Comment: You're right, it does reduce load and memory a bit. Now I'm only at 24%-30% load when the page is loaded vs 2-3% with the browser closed. USed to be around 50% so much better; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same concept. I used Javascript to create a real-time pages showing stock market prices, and its been almost a year and i could not find the memory leak.

I tried checking with google chrome tools like heap snapshot to check the differences in the heaps and to identify which objects are being accumalted and notices that the JSON data that i am receiving from the server as string is not being garbage collected for some reason. And this was killing the page performance, like if you kept the page open for a day or so either the browser will crash or the whole PC will hang.

I read alot of articles for best practices in using Closures and better memory management specially with IE, but the final thing i found as a killer for this issue is a javascript compiler where you input a javascript with closures and it will convert the closures to normal function calls. https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/

Comment: yes, tried with that too but it didn't change the memory usage

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the effect of the fading. Because the browser has to render the colors again every time you change the opacitiy. If you remove the code that changes the opacity the CPU usage seems to be much lower for me.

I don't have a solution though. The only thing I can think of is a animated gif as background (which isn't a good solution I think).